# How to convert html form fields in to excel or cvv using java

Tags: java

I have created a page with a registration form using bootstrap, and back end coding is done in Java. I don't want to use a database. When the user fills in the registration form and clicks on submit, all entered data should get stored in an Excel or csv file. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What are you asking exactly ? You want some recommendation on API or tutorial to check ? In this case your question is off topic cause answers will be opinion-based. Or are you asking how to do it ? in this case, please provide us what you've tried and what issue you are facing. otherwise your question seems like you are asking us to do your job.

Comment: I have written following code:

Comment: </head>
   <body>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" data-form-field="Name" required="" id="name-form1-6">
   <input type="submit" value="Export to EXCEL" onclick="write_to_excel();"/>
      <table><tr><td>First</td><td>second</td></tr></table>

      </body>
      </html>

Comment: for this i want on submit data should be displayed in excel

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49771465/edit) your question to put your code in, instead of posting it inside comment

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend https://jsoup.org/ java library

Answer (score 0):

Try This From:- http://www.databison.com/html-to-excel-using-javascript-and-excel-to-html-using-vba/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function write_to_excel()
     {
         str="";

         var mytable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
          var row_Count = mytable.rows.length;
         var col_Count = mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("td").length;   

         var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
         var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
          ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;

for(var i=0; i < row_count ; i++)
{  
    for(var j=0; j < col_Count; j++)
    {          
        str= mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j].innerHTML;
        ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1,j+1).Value = str;
    }
}

     }
     </script></script></head>
   <body>
   <input type="submit" value="Export to EXCEL" onclick="write_to_excel();"/>
      <table><tr><td>First</td><td>second</td></tr></table>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: will this give excel sheet at server side??